Untangling my org
Over these years, I have done numerous mini projects in my DE. To manage my changes better, I would like to split my org into multiple unlocked packages. However I intend to manage all the packages in a single sfdx project.
I would also like to have one repo for each package but I'm not sure how it would fan out with my desired setup.
The concern I have in having one repo per package is, if I make a change to a component that is shared across packages, how would it be possible to distribute those changes across repos?
